# Show that a function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

How can I show that this function is measurable?

$f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R : (x,y) \to \begin{cases} (1-xy)^{-1}, &\text{ if } xy\ne1\\0 &\text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$

Comment: Hi, Tyler, welcome to Math.SE! Please update your question with your own thoughts on how to approach the problem, and we will be happy to guide you. Can you include the definition of measurability and explain how you can check it for this particular function?

Comment: @gt6989b: You're a bit late, the OP has been a MSE user for 52 days already! Oh, and adding the definition of measurability wouldn't be useful here: I believe that this problem is not meant to be solved with the definition.

Comment: @AlexM. it would show some effort on the problem though...

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function $g_n (x,y) = \frac 1 {1-xy}$ defined on $\{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \mid 1-xy \ge \frac 1 n\}$. Consider $h_n$ a continuous function defined on $\{(x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \mid 1-xy \le \frac 1 n\}$ such that $h_n = 0$ when $x=y$ and $h_n = g_n$ when $1 - xy = \frac 1 n$ (i.e. on the boundary). Finally, consider

$$f_n(x,y) = \begin{cases} g_n(x,y), & 1-xy > \frac 1 n \\ h_n(x,y), & 1-xy \le \frac 1 n .\end{cases}$$

Since $h_n$ and $g_n$ agree on the boundary, and they are both continuous, it follows that $f_n$ is continuous, too, therefore measurable. Since $f_n \to f$, it follows that $f$ will be measurable too. (This is nice about measurability, that it is preserved by pointwise limits - unlike continuity, which is not).

Comment: This is a very nice answer, as it is easy to understand and allows to emphasize on the behaviour of measurable functions.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer: ...On the other hand, explicitly writing down a formula for $h_n$ is doable, but messy (one either goes formally, with Urysohn's lemma, or tries to patch some bump-type functions into the desired result).

Comment: Indeed, but measurability is often tricky to check, so I believe that appealing to some technical lemma's is not such a big deal if, in the end, one understands what is going on and how to think about this kind of problems.

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$D = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \, | \, xy \neq 1 \}, \\
H = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 \, | \, xy = 1 \} = \{ (1,1) \}. $$

and $g = f|_D$. If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we can describe $f^{-1}(U)$ by considering two cases:

1. If $0 \notin U$ then $f^{-1}(U) = g^{-1}(U)$.
2. If $0 \in U$ then $f^{-1}(U) = g^{-1}(U) \cup H$.

Note that $g$ is continuous. Now, if $U$ is open and $0 \notin U$ then $f^{-1}(U) = g^{-1}(U)$ is open (in $D$), hence it is of the form $[0,1]^2 \cap V$ for some open $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and measurable. If $U$ is open and $0 \in U$ then $f^{-1}(U) = g^{-1}(U) \cup H$ has the form $([0,1]^2 \cap V) \cup H$ where $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $H$ is closed, we see that again this is measurable.

Since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by open subsets, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:the inverse image of an open subset by $f$ is open if it does not contain $0$ or is the Union of an open subset and $\{xy=1, x,y\in [0,1]\}$ so it is always a Borelian.